# My program is taking very long to print out results over 25, is there a way to make this more efficient when I run?

Tags: python, math, python-3.6

These are the lines I'm using, it produces a list of the possible combinations of the sum to an integer typed in and then states the amount of combinations.

```
import itertools

val = int(input())
r = range(val)[1:]
res = []    
for i in range(len(r)+1):
    res += [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(r, i) if sum(list(x)) == val]    
print("Solution : %s " % res)
print("Combinations : %s" % len(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calculating every single possible combination, and then keeping only the combinations that satisfy your sum condition. The combination pool it is searching through grows at a rate 2^(n-1) which you can see by commenting out the condition part:

```
import itertools
import time

startTime = time.time()

val = 21
r = range(val)[1:]
res = []    
for i in range(len(r)+1):
    res += [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(r, i)]# if sum(list(x)) == val]    
#print("Solution : %s " % res)
print("Combinations : %s" % len(res))

print(time.time() - startTime, 'seconds')
```

Try this:

```
def a(lst, target, with_replacement=False):
    def _a(idx, l, r, t, w):
        if t == sum(l): r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            _a(u if w else (u + 1), l + [lst[u]], r, t, w)
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target, with_replacement)

val = 50
s = range(1, val)
solutions = a(s, val)
print(solutions)
print(len(solutions))
```

which is modified from code by thefourtheye: 
[Finding Combinations to the provided Sum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193555/finding-combinations-to-the-provided-sum-value)

timing it:
original code:

```
val = 24, t = 6.5917372703552253 seconds
val = 25, t = 13.705767631530762 seconds
val = 26, t = 27.934977531433105 seconds
val = 50, t = 459889248.39282094 seconds
```

above method:

```
val = 24, t = 0.0084612369537353 seconds
val = 25, t = 0.0069310665130615 seconds
val = 26, t = 0.0085859298706054 seconds
val = 50, t = 0.4947729110717773 seconds
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is return every combination of numbers that are less than n and do not repeat. So for input 6, the return would be [1,5], [1,2,3], [2,4]. My code returns these fine and then states the number of combinations, in this case, 3, but when I input values larger than 25 the return takes much longer, I understand the return is exponential but the results of 141 combinations shouldn't take as long as it is.

Comment: What your code is doing is finding every single combination including invalid ones, and then chucking away everything except the few you want to keep. So for a sum value of 25, thats 16,777,216 combinations your code searches through to find the valid ones. And all these combinations double with every increment to your value. I edited my answer with a working solution that works far faster at these scales

Comment: Oh I see now, that is much faster. Thank you

Comment: Zulfiqaar: You shouldn't blindly copy code. The `with_replacement` keyword argument isn't actually _used_ for anything in the `a()` or `_a()` functions (except being passed from the former to the latter so it can ignore it, too).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to improve the speed. I tried (and noticed that it makes a big difference) a simple one: getting rid of the repeated conversions between generators and lists. Here's your code, modified:

```
import time
import itertools

#val = int(input("val:"))
#r = range(val)[1:]

def simple_time_func(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("{} took {:.3f} seconds.".format(func.__name__, time.time() - start))
        return r
    return wrapper

@simple_time_func
def original(val, r):
    res = list()
    for i in range(len(r) + 1):
        res += [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(r, i) if sum(list(x)) == val]
    return res

@simple_time_func
def improved0(val, r):
    res = list()
    for i in range(len(r) + 1):
        res += [x for x in itertools.combinations(r, i) if sum(x) == val]
    return res


for val in range(21, 28):
    r = range(val)[1:]
    print("\nval: {}".format(val))
    for func in (original, improved0):
        res = func(val, r)
        #print("    Solution : %s " % res)
        #print("    Combinations : %s" % len(res))
```

**Notes**:

- I took the expensive portion (the `for` loop) and encapsulated it in a function (`original`) in order to time it
- I placed the improved loop in another function (called it `improved0`)
- The rest of the code (unfortunately, also the most of it) is simply for performance testing

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q46853086>"c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" a.py
>
> val: 21
> original took 0.573 seconds.
> improved0 took 0.325 seconds.
>
> val: 22
> original took 1.185 seconds.
> improved0 took 0.633 seconds.
>
> val: 23
> original took 2.388 seconds.
> improved0 took 1.300 seconds.
>
> val: 24
> original took 4.880 seconds.
> improved0 took 2.609 seconds.
>
> val: 25
> original took 9.796 seconds.
> improved0 took 5.243 seconds.
>
> val: 26
> original took 19.701 seconds.
> improved0 took 10.489 seconds.
>
> val: 27
> original took 39.314 seconds.
> improved0 took 21.559 seconds.
> ```

As the output shows, this apparently insignificant change almost cuts the time in half.
Next step consists of **real** optimization (as the computational complexity still looks exponential), regarding efficient usage of mathematical and programming skills, to improve the speed even more (unfortunately I'm running out of time).

Comment: thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll get back to this since I feel that there is a (much) faster way.