# Function that find combination of values that sums to a given number

Tags: python

This post [Finding Combinations to the provided Sum value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194023/1561176) presents the function `subsets_with_sum()`. It finds a combination of values in an array which the sum is equal to a given value. But since the post is over 6 years old, I made this post to ask: how does this function work? What is it doing?

```
def subsets_with_sum(lst, target, with_replacement=False):
    x = 0 if with_replacement else 1
    def _a(idx, l, r, t):
        if t == sum(l): r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            _a(u + x, l + [lst[u]], r, t)
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, I'll just add some line breaks to make it a bit easier to read:

```py
def subsets_with_sum(lst, target, with_replacement=False):
    x = 0 if with_replacement else 1
    def _a(idx, l, r, t):
        if t == sum(l): 
            r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): 
            return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            _a(u + x, l + [lst[u]], r, t)
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target)
```

First thing you'll notice is that the `subsets_with_sum` defines a function and calls it once in the last `return` statement. The first element is your list from which you sample values, the second is the target sum, and third is an parameter that tells the function whether a single element from `lst` can be used multiple times.

Because the `_a` is defined within the `subsets_with_sum` it is *enclosed* with the values passed to `subsets_with_sum` - this is important, `lst` is the same for every recursive call of `_a`. The second thing to notice is that `l` is a list of values, whereas `r` is a *list of lists*. Importantly, `l` is a different object for each `_a` call (that's due to `l + [lst[u]]` resulting in a copy of `l` concatenated with `[lst[u]]`). However, `r` denotes the *same* object for each `_a` call - `r.append(l)` modifies it in place.

I'll start with `with_replacement == True` because I find it simpler. With the first call `_a` is passed `0, [], [], target`. It then checks if `t == sum(l)` and appends it to `r`, hence the only elements of `r` will be lists that sum to `t` (or `target`). If `sum(l)` that recursive branch is discarded by returning `None`. If the elements of `l` sum to a value lesser then `target` then for **each** element from the `lst` the element is appended to a *copy* of  `l` and `_a` is called with that list. Here's an amended version of the function that prints out the steps, so we can inspect what happens:

```py
def subsets_with_sum(lst, target, with_replacement=False):
    x = 0 if with_replacement else 1
    def _a(idx, l, r, t, c):
        if t == sum(l): 
            r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): 
            return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            print("{}. l = {} and l + [lst[u]] = {}".format(c, l, l + [lst[u]]))
            _a(u + x, l + [lst[u]], r, t, c+1)
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target, 0)
```

Calling `subsets_with_sum([1,2,3], 2, True)` the following gets printed (I re-ordered and separated the printed lines a bit so they're easier to read):

```py
0. l = [] and l + [lst[u]] = [1]
0. l = [] and l + [lst[u]] = [2]
0. l = [] and l + [lst[u]] = [3]

1. l = [1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1]
1. l = [2] and l + [lst[u]] = [2, 2]
1. l = [2] and l + [lst[u]] = [2, 3]
1. l = [1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 2]
1. l = [1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 3]

2. l = [1, 1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1, 1]
2. l = [1, 1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1, 2]
2. l = [1, 1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1, 3]
```

You can see that the right column (`l + [lst[u]]`) at a level `c` is equal to the left column (`l`) at a level `c + 1`. Furthermore, observe that `[3]` - the last line where `c == 0` doesn't make it past the `elif t < sum(l)`, hence it doesn't get printed. Similarly, `[2]` at `c == 1` gets appended to `r`, but nonetheless the branch continues to the next level, since one or more elements of the `lst` might be equal to 0, hence appending them to `[2]` might result in *another* list that sums to the `target`.

Also, observe that for each list at certain level `c`, whose last element is `lst[u]` will appear `len(lst) - u`-times at the next level, `c + 1`, because that's the number of combinations of the list for each `lst[z]`, where `z >= u`.

So what happens with `with_replacement == False` (the default case)? Well, in that case each time `lst[u]` is added to `l` and `sum(l) < t`, so that that specific instance of `l` continues to the next recursion level only `lst[z]` can be added to the list, where `z > u`, since `u + 1` is passed to the respective `_a` call. Let's look what happens when we call `subsets_with_sum([1,2,3], 2, False)`:

```py
0. l = [] and l + [lst[u]] = [1]
0. l = [] and l + [lst[u]] = [3]
0. l = [] and l + [lst[u]] = [2]

1. l = [1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1]
1. l = [1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 2]
1. l = [1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 3]
1. l = [2] and l + [lst[u]] = [2, 2]
1. l = [2] and l + [lst[u]] = [2, 3]

2. l = [1, 1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1, 1]
2. l = [1, 1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1, 2]
2. l = [1, 1] and l + [lst[u]] = [1, 1, 3]
```

Now observe that for each list at certain level `c`, whose last element is `lst[u]` will appear `len(lst) - u - 1`-times at the next level, `c + 1`, because that's the number of combinations of the list for each `lst[z]`, where `z > u`. Compare this with the `with_replacement=True` analyzed above.

I suggest you play around with it somewhat more until you understand it better. Regardless of substitution, what is important to realize is that the return statements always return to the caller. The first call of the `_a` returns to the `subsets_with_sum` which then returns to the caller (presumably you or some other function). All other (recursive) calls to `_a` return to the previous instances of `_a` calls which just discard the returned value (or more precisely, don't bother to do anything with it). The reason you get back the right `r` is because it behaves somewhat like a global value - each `_a` call that finds a solution, adds it to the same `r`.

Finally, the `subsets_with_sum` doesn't work exactly like I'd expect it to based on its desired functionality. Try the following two calls: `subsets_with_sum([2,2,1], 5, True)` and `subsets_with_sum([2,2,1,1,1], 5, False)`.

Comment: Hi, this explanation is clear enough for me, but what if i want to get the indices of the values instead of the values? Is there any way to modify the function to return the indices of the combinations?

Comment: Nevermind i just changed the line 4 and 10 as follow:

`if t == sum([lst[index] for index in l])` and  `_a(u + x, l + [u], r, t)`